# Can't output the ('text_field,) from Advanced custom fields

Tags: php

i'm trying to get the title under my image. I made a &text and what is the next step?

```
   if ( ! empty( $vorespartnere ) ) {
foreach ( $vorespartnere as $partnere ) {
    $image = get_field( 'partner_logo', $partnere );
    $text = get_field( 'text_field', $partnere );

    if ( ! empty( $image) && ! is_wp_error() ) {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt=""> 
        <?php

    }



}
```

}

Comment: Please format your question properly with all the fields you've used.

Answer (score 0):

You can Prefer All Custom filed on this site https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/